# How to search information from Ontology?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, ontology

I have developed an Ontology for University by using Protege and currently I used SPARQL for accessing data from this university ontology as I have installed Protege in my local machine but once I upload this ontology on World Wide Web, then how people can fire query to this ontology because on their machine Protege may not be available? In current WWW, we just write text in google search engine but how we can search any information from Ontology by using Semantic Web Search enginee like SWOOGLE?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should store your ontology within a triple store e.g [Jena](http://jena.sourceforge.net/). In the next step, your application should provide a service like in the http://dbpedia.org/sparql/ so that other people can query your underlying ontology through SPARQL. Jena has support for SPARQL execution. You can see the link [ARQ](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/).

For doing keyword search on the ontology, I think you can you use [LARQ](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/lucene-arq.html) (ARQ+Lucene). It provides indexing of ontology resources and enables keyword search on them.

Answer (score 2):

The native triple store of Jena is [TDB](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/). You also can setup on top of it a [Fuseki server](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/) (from the Jena project as well) in order to expose a Sparql endpoint.

Once you have all your triplets in TDB you can perform SPARQL queries to the Fuseki server and get your results.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilise an online SPARQL editor, such as this one from [sparql.org](http://sparql.org/sparql.html), or you can index your ontology by [Sindice](http://sindice.com/) and leaverage the capacities of this search engine.